# Customize version number in Swagger

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using the default swagger implementation with my dotnet core webapi.
I would like the actual version number to appear instead of the template whenever version number is changing from the "select a definition" dropdown on top right corner.

So, for example when v2 is selected from the dropdown, it should appear like this

[image]

instead of this,

[image]

Any clues how this can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` and custom swagger filter.

Create custom document filter;

```
public class ReplaceVersionWithExactValueInPathFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        var paths = swaggerDoc.Paths;

        swaggerDoc.Paths = new OpenApiPaths();

        foreach (var path in paths)
        {
            var key = path.Key.Replace("v{version}", swaggerDoc.Info.Version);

            var value = path.Value;

            swaggerDoc.Paths.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Add versioning and swagger services to your service collection;

```
services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
{
    // Specify the default API Version
    config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);

    // If the client hasn't specified the API version in the request, use the default API version number 
    config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;

    // Advertise the API versions supported for the particular endpoint
    config.ReportApiVersions = true;
});

//Adding swagger services
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    //other configurations 

    options.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1.0",
        Title = "Your Api Title",
        Description = "Your Api Description",
        TermsOfService = new Uri("https://yourcompany.com"),
        Contact = new OpenApiContact { Name = "Your Company", Email = "info@yourcompany.com", Url = new Uri("https://yourcompany.com") },
        License = new OpenApiLicense { Name = "MIT", Url = new Uri("https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT") }
    });

    options.SwaggerDoc("v2.0", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v2.0",
        Title = "Your Api Title",
        Description = "Your Api Description",
        TermsOfService = new Uri("https://yourcompany.com"),
        Contact = new OpenApiContact { Name = "Your Company", Email = "info@yourcompany.com", Url = new Uri("https://yourcompany.com") },
        License = new OpenApiLicense { Name = "MIT", Url = new Uri("https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT") }
    });
        
    options.DocumentFilter<ReplaceVersionWithExactValueInPathFilter>();

    //other configurations 
});
```

Register `Swagger` and `SwaggerUI` middleware;

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
    c.RouteTemplate = "api/docs/{documentName}/docs.json";
}).UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/api/docs/v1.0/docs.json", "v1.0");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/api/docs/v2.0/docs.json", "v2.0");
});
```

Then configure your controller;

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestsController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost("Test")]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v1.0")]
    public IActionResult TestV1()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    
    [HttpPost("Test")]
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "v2.0")]
    public IActionResult TestV2()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

If you want to remove version header from your document you should use this;

```
public class VersionHeaderFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
         if (operation.Parameters != null)
         {
             var versionParameter = operation.Parameters.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name == "version");

             if (versionParameter != null) 
                 operation.Parameters.Remove(versionParameter);
         }
    }
}
```

---

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
     //other configurations 

     options.OperationFilter<VersionHeaderFilter>();

     //other configurations 
});
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks. This worked with one minor modification. I had to replace `var key = path.Key.Replace("v{version}", swaggerDoc.Info.Version);` with `var key = path.Key.Replace("v{version}", context.DocumentName);`